# Interrupt a recvfrom() call in Python using a specific key press

Tags: python, while-loop, key, interrupt

I have a while loop in Python calling a function that is expecting to receieve a message from an UDP client with a recvfrom() call.

I would like to know if it is possible to interrupt the message reception process using, for example, the '+' key.
After this key press the app could allow additional options such as sending a message.

Don't know if this can be done without using threading.

I'm using Python 3.10.6 and Linux

```
import socket
import sys

# Parse app checker
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    # Get "IP address of Server" and also the "port number" from argument 1 and argument 2
    ip = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])
else:
    print("Run like : python3 server.py <arg1:server ip:this system IP 192.168.1.6> <arg2:server port:4444 >")
    exit(1)

# Create a UDP socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = (ip, port)
s.bind(server_address)

def fun_recv_data():
    global address
    data, address = s.recvfrom(4096)
    print (data)

while True:
    # Receive data
    fun_recv_data()
```